# Querying Neo4j to get paths between specific nodes with multiple relationships types

Tags: neo4j

For a single relationship type the query is working fine:

```
MATCH p=(a)-[:CHILD_OF* ]-(b)
WHERE a.Id=8 AND b.Id=10
RETURN p
ORDER BY length(p) ASC LIMIT 3
```

What I want is something like the following with specific multiple relationship types:

```
MATCHp=(a)-[:SIBLING_OF|CHILD_OF|SPOUSE_OF* ]-(b)
WHERE a.Id=8 AND b.Id=10
RETURN p 
ORDER BY length(p) ASC LIMIT 3
```

Edit: When I'm running the second query above it displays "Executing query..." and after 3 to 4 minutes of execution returns the multiple paths of SPOUSE_OF and only one path for other relationship types.

With the query below I get the following error: 
 "Invalid input '|': expected whitespace, RangeLiteral, a property map or ']'"

```
MATCH p=(a)-[:SIBLING_OF*|CHILD_OF*|SPOUSE_OF* ]-(b)
WHERE a.Id=8 AND b.Id=10
RETURN p 
ORDER BY length(p) ASC LIMIT 3
```

Comment: Is the cyphershortestpath function can fit your needs ?

Comment: @logisima I need the first three paths the first one being the shortest path, the second shortest path as well the third shortest path.

Comment: If all your path should have the same length, there is also the allShortestPath function.
With your patternNeo4j will build all the path that match it, and this can lead to a huge amount of path (and you can also travers all the graph).
That's why I'm trying to know if you can use a shrotestpath algo.

Comment: @logisima The paths should not have the same length. The first path must be the shortest path, and other paths must be progressively longer.

Comment: The multiplicity on the relationship should extend to all the types given, not just the last (so any combination of the paths given, with any multiplicity). That should be working in your second query. Is the problem that it isn't doing what you want it to do, or that you want to try to improve its performance? If it isn't doing what you want it to do, can you clarify that in your description?

Comment: Your second query seems correct. Since you are limiting your results to just 3 paths (with the shortest lengths), you may not be seeing other paths that have a wider mixture of relationship types. Try changing your `LIMIT 3` to something larger, like `LIMIT 20`.

Comment: @cybersam yes the second query is working my mistake was I thought it was not working because it taking too long to execute. I waited for it to complete execution and It takes about 2 minutes and 10 seconds to execute.

Comment: @Ntokozo Can you add PROFILE to the start of your query, expand all the nodes in your profile tree, and add the profiling image to your description? I don't think any of us can offer much performance advice without that.

Comment: @InverseFalcon I'm not able to use PROFILE keyword I get the following error: Invalid input 'P': expected  (line 1, column 1)
"PROFILE "
 ^

Comment: @Ntokozo That is very strange. The PROFILE keyword has been available since 2013 at least. `profile return 1` should work, and if it works, you should be able to use `profile` in your query: `profile match p=`.... If profile still isn't working, can you use `EXPLAIN`?

Comment: @InverseFalcon Yes it very strange indeed I did also use EXPLAIN and seems like it not recognising the keywords PROFILE/EXPLAIN because I keep getting the same error. Even a simple query like the following is not working: "profile match n-[r]-m return m"